# How to set custom Dropdown on Top Menu in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, frontend, topmenu

I want to set my custom **div** on my custom **Brands** link in Top Menu like 
[image]
I create my custom **link** in **Top Menu** the code is

```
<?php

namespace Vender\Module\Plugin\Block;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory;

class Topmenu
{
    /**
     * @var NodeFactory
     */
    protected $nodeFactory;

    public function __construct(
        NodeFactory $nodeFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        Data $helper
    )
    {
        $this->nodeFactory = $nodeFactory;
        $this->_storeManager=$storeManager;
        $this->_helper = $helper;
    }

    public function beforeGetHtml(
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $subject
    )
    {
        $node = $this->nodeFactory->create(
            [
                'data' => $this->getNodeAsArray(),
                'idField' => 'id',
                'tree' => $subject->getMenu()->getTree()
            ]
        );
        $subject->getMenu()->addChild($node);
    }

    protected function getNodeAsArray()
    {
            return [
                'name' => __('Brands'),
                'id' => 'pmebrands',
                'url' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()
                        ->getBaseUrl().'shop-bybrand.html',
                'has_active' => false,
                'is_active' => false
            ];


    }
}
```

now the code is showing the link perfectly on top menu
but the problem is how can I set my custom **div** to show on my custom link **Brands** mouse hover?